# How do I Bind Visiblity of a Control(StackPanel) based on a TextBox Value?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a `TextBox` `TxtFruit` and two `StackPanel`s `stackPanelApple` and `stackPanelOrange` respectively in an WPF MVVM application.

This is what should happen:

- If `txtFruit.Text` is "Apple", then `stackPanelApple` would be visible
- If `txtFruit.Text` is changed to "Orange" then `stackPanelOrange` will be displayed
- If `txtFruit.Text` is empty or something else, both of the panel's `Visibility` should be `Collapsed`.

How do I achieve this in my view model?

```
<TextBox x:Name="TxtFruit" Text="{Binding CurrentFruit}"/>
<StackPanel>
   <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanelApple" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,20" >
      <TextBox x:Name="AppleProperty1" Margin="0,0,10,0" Text="{Binding AppleProperty1}" />
      <TextBox x:Name="AppleProperty2" Margin="10,0,10,0" Text="{Binding AppleProperty2}" />
   </StackPanel>
   <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanelOrange" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,20" >
      <TextBox x:Name="OrangeProperty1" Margin="0,0,10,0" Text="{Binding OrangeProperty1}" />
      <TextBox x:Name="OrangeProperty1" Margin="10,0,10,0" Text="{Binding OrangeProperty2}"/>
   </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to do this in a view model. You can solve this with data triggers in a style, e.g.:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
   <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=TxtFruit}" Value="Apple">
         <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

However, a less verbose variant could be to write a value converter that checks for equality of a bound value and a parameter. If both are equal, it returns `Visible`, otherwise `Collapsed`.

```
public class EqualityToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      return value != null && value.Equals(parameter) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
   }
}
```

Create an instance of the converter in any resources, e.g. in your application resource dictionary.

```
<local:EqualityToVisibilityConverter x:Key="EqualityToVisibilityConverter"/>
```

Then you can easily reuse the converter to bind the visibility without a style.

```
<TextBox x:Name="TxtFruit" Text="{Binding CurrentFruit}"/>
<StackPanel>
   <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanelApple" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,20"
               Visibility="{Binding Text, ElementName=TxtFruit, Converter={StaticResource EqualityToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=Apple}">
      <TextBox x:Name="AppleProperty1" Margin="0,0,10,0" Text="{Binding AppleProperty1}"/>
      <TextBox x:Name="AppleProperty2" Margin="10,0,10,0" Text="{Binding AppleProperty2}"/>
   </StackPanel>
   <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanelOrange" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,20"
               Visibility="{Binding Text, ElementName=TxtFruit, Converter={StaticResource EqualityToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=Orange}">
      <TextBox x:Name="OrangeProperty1" Margin="0,0,10,0" Text="{Binding OrangeProperty1}"/>
      <TextBox x:Name="OrangeProperty1" Margin="10,0,10,0" Text="{Binding OrangeProperty2}"/>
   </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Amazing! Using  `Data Triggers ` is fine. But I rather stick to the `Value Converter` Method. I very much appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using style and triggers in the XAML view:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TxtFruit" Text="{Binding CurrentFruit}"/>
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanelApple" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,20" >
        <TextBox x:Name="AppleProperty1" Margin="0,0,10,0" Text="{Binding AppleProperty1}" />
        <TextBox x:Name="AppleProperty2" Margin="10,0,10,0" Text="{Binding AppleProperty2}" />
        <StackPanel.Style>
            <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=TxtFruit}" Value="Apple">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Style>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanelOrange" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,20" >
        <TextBox x:Name="OrangeProperty1" Margin="0,0,10,0" Text="{Binding OrangeProperty1}" />
        <TextBox x:Name="OrangeProperty2" Margin="10,0,10,0" Text="{Binding OrangeProperty2}"/>
        <StackPanel.Style>
            <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text, ElementName=TxtFruit}" Value="Orange">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Style>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: That works like a charm. But I needed a solution more like non xaml. Thank you so much.